# C++ Direct 2D How To Resize ID2D1Bitmap

Tags: c++, bitmap, resize, direct2d

I'm making myself a simple GUI library for a game I'm making and each control needs to have a Bitmap to draw to when the control needs redrawing. When it does not need to be redrawn, it will have an already made bitmap ready to display to the screen. Since controls can be resized, this Bitmap also needs to be resized so the control can be fully drawn into it properly. How can I achieve this since it does not appear to be a Resize method to resize a bitmap, unlike an ID2D1HwndRenderTarget, which can be resized?

Comment: There is no simple function that exists inside the DirectX libraries for resizing a ID2D1Bitmap. As further clarification. You could resize it by saving the raw image data and applying different sampling algorithms to it. But there are no BUILT-IN functions that will do that for you.

Comment: What effect do you want to achieve?

Comment: I"m making myself a simple GUI library for a game I'm making and each control needs to have a Bitmap to draw to when the control needs redrawing. When it does not need to be redrawn, it will have an already made bitmap ready to display to the screen. Since controls can be resized, this Bitmap also needs to be resized so the control can be fully drawn into it properly.

Comment: why not put this to your question to make it more clear?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to resize `ID2D1Bitmap`. The dimensions are set once the bitmap is created. Same applies to `IDXGISurface` and `ID3D11Texture2D`. 
You are going to need to create a new bitmap with a different size and copy the data yourself.

Comment: This is half right, you do need to create a new bitmap with the desired size - but you do not need to "copy data" per say, you can draw the old bitmap to the new bitmap by creating a render target and calling `dc->DrawImage`. If you just need a crop, you're done. If you need to also scale the image, the effect `CLSID_D2D1Scale` or a world transform (`dc->SetTransform`) can be used during drawing to achieve the desired level of scaling.